# Hold reference to interface method and apply it to an implementation of that interface

Tags: c#, interface, reference, delegates

I have multiple state classes that each implements an `IState` interface, defining the kinds of methods that can be called on each:

```
public interface IState
{
    Type BanknoteInserted(Banknote banknoteInfo);
    Type SwitchToggled(bool switchEnabled);
    Type CardDataReceived(string track1Data, string track2Data, string track3Data);
}
```

I have a `CurrentState` property that changes to point to whichever current `IState` implementation that is loaded.

Separately (driven by hardware or user interactions), I have events that need to execute those methods on `CurrentState`. For threading simplicity and other reasons, those events are enqueued and processed in sequence in a background thread.

How can I refer to a particular interface method in my queue, such that I can "apply" the method to whatever class is currently set as `CurrentState` when that queue item is dequeued?

Each method call in the queue should be able to receive meaningful, typed method parameters (set at the time the item is enqueued).

The only option that I've been able to get working is to fall back on reflection and to insert tuples of `(string methodName, object[] methodParameters)` into my queue, but is that the best option? It feels like I should be able to use delegates for this.

Comment: If `BankNote` is immutable (`bool` and `string` are) then can you not enqueue `Action<IState>` lambdas in your queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create a class that holds callbacks for each method of `IState`:

```
public class Callbacks
{
    public static readonly Func<IState, Banknote, Type> OnBanknoteInserted = 
      (s, b) => s.BanknoteInserted(b);
    // and so on, for each method

    public Func<IState, Banknote, Type> BanknoteInserted { get; set; }
    // and so on, for each method
}
```

Then on enqueue:

```
// put method that should be invoked on dequeue
queue.Enqueue(new Callbacks { BanknoteInserted = Callbacks.OnBanknoteInserted});
```

And then on dequeue you may do like this:

```
Callbacks callback = queue.Dequeue();
if (callback.BanknoteInserted != null)
    return callback.BanknoteInserted(CurrentState, banknote);
// else if (callback.SwitchToggled != null)
// and so on...
```

**EDIT:**  To save arguments on `Enqueue` consider this approach:
Define an interface

```
public interface IStateMethod
{
    Type FireEvent(IState currentState);
}
```

Create implementations for each method in `IState` like this:

```
public class BanknoteInsertedMethod : IStateMethod
{
    private readonly Banknote banknote;

    // save all parameters here
    public BanknoteInsertedMethod(Banknote banknote)
    {
        this.banknote = banknote;
    }

    public Type FireEvent(IState currentState)
    {
        return currentState.BanknoteInserted(this.banknote);
    }
}
```

Now you can do `Eqnueue`

```
var queue = new Queue<IStateMethod>();
queue.Enqueue(new BanknoteInsertedMethod(banknote));
```

Then on `Dequeue` simply call `FireEvent`:

```
IStateMethod stateMethod = queue.Dequeue();
return stateMethod.FireEvent(currentState);
```

Comment: This looks close, but I need to be able to pass callback arguments on *enqueue*, not *dequeue*. The arguments are often implicit properties of the event is being handled (e.g. mag stripe data for a card swipe, or banknote data for a banknote insertion).

Comment: Thanks Aleks. This seems like the option that works best for us.